# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Tensor' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python, pytorch, neural-network, torch

I'm trying to build a Transformer model, but it produces an error of

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Tensor' and 'NoneType'
```

It happens in this code:

```
xe = np.random.randint(0, 20_000, size=(8,512)) # batch size of 8 ;; sequence length 512
xe_t = torch.tensor(xe).to(device)

xd = np.random.randint(0, 10_000, size=(8, 256))
xd_t = torch.tensor(xd).to(device)

maske = np.ones((8, 512))
maske[:, 256:] = 0
maske_t = torch.tensor(maske).to(device)

maskd = np.ones((8, 256))
maskd[:, 128:] = 0
maskd_t = torch.tensor(maskd).to(device)

out = transformer(xe_t, xd_t, maske_t, maskd_t)
out.shape
```

I'm trying to understand the error.
Here is the error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[11], line 15
     12 maskd[:, 128:] = 0
     13 maskd_t = torch.tensor(maskd).to(device)
---> 15 out = transformer(xe_t, xd_t, maske_t, maskd_t)
     16 out.shape

File ~\anaconda3\envs\ml\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:1194, in Module._call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1190 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1191 # this function, and just call forward.
   1192 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1193         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1194     return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1195 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1196 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

Cell In[8], line 8, in Transformer.forward(self, enc_input, dec_input, enc_mask, dec_mask)
      7 def forward(self, enc_input, dec_input, enc_mask, dec_mask):
----> 8     enc_output = self.encoder(enc_input, enc_mask)
      9     dec_output = self.decoder(enc_output, dec_input, enc_mask, dec_mask)
     10     return dec_output

File ~\anaconda3\envs\ml\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:1194, in Module._call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1190 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1191 # this function, and just call forward.
   1192 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1193         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1194     return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1195 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1196 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

Cell In[6], line 30, in Encoder.forward(self, x, pad_mask)
     28 x = self.pos_encoding(x)
     29 for block in self.transformer_blocks:
---> 30     x = block(x, pad_mask)
     32 # many-to-one (x has the shape N x T x D)
     33 # x = x[:, 0, :]
     35 x = self.ln(x)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\ml\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:1194, in Module._call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1190 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1191 # this function, and just call forward.
   1192 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1193         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1194     return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1195 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1196 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

Cell In[3], line 17, in EncoderBlock.forward(self, x, pad_mask)
     16 def forward(self, x, pad_mask=None):
---> 17     x = self.ln1(x + self.mha(x, x, x, pad_mask))
     18     x = self.ln2(x + self.ann(x))
     19     x = self.dropout(x)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Tensor' and 'NoneType'`
```

I can't find anything off in my code, I tried looking for solutions.

Comment: Can you please show the definition of the method `mha` that is called in `self.mha(x, x, x, pad_mask)` in line 17 of cell `In[3]`?

Comment: It looks like your code is defined in some IPython interactive interpreter, which is prone for bugs like missed definitions, overrides, etc. Apart from that, it looks like the method `mha` doesn't return anything, while the code assumes it should

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bro The error you're encountering indicates that you are trying to add a Tensor object to a NoneType object, which is not supported. This issue is occurring in the line x = self.ln1(x + self.mha(x, x, x, pad_mask)) inside the EncoderBlock class
so you have to  ensure that the pad_mask parameter passed to the self.mha function is not None you have to midfy the code  try this one

class EncoderBlock(nn.Module): def **init**(self, d_model, num_heads, d_ff, dropout_rate): super(EncoderBlock, self).**init**() self.mha = MultiheadAttention(d_model, num_heads) self.ln1 = nn.LayerNorm(d_model) self.ann = nn.Sequential( nn.Linear(d_model, d_ff), nn.ReLU(), nn.Linear(d_ff, d_model), ) self.ln2 = nn.LayerNorm(d_model) self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout_rate def forward(self, x, pad_mask=None): attn_output = self.mha(x, x, x, pad_mask) x = self.ln1(x + attn_output) x = self.ln2(x + self.ann(x)) x = self.dropout(x) return x

dont forget  to  implemented the MultiheadAttention class or imported it correctly because it's  is not included in the code snippet you provided and if  this solution didn't work with you just ge me the  implementation of the MultiheadAttention class or module you are using so ican understand it more

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: None type is not allowed I have alsoe the same problem and I'm fixing like that:         red_mask = red_mask.float()  # Convert mask to a float tensor (0.0 for non-red, 1.0 for red)